# File missing in ajax:AsyncFileUpload on saving

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ajax:AsyncFileUpload on my asp file

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="modalActLogAction" runat="server" >    
      <ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="fuActionAttachment" runat="server" Width="240px" OnClientUploadComplete = "OnClientUploadCompleteFn"/>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is when I try to access after submitting the file, its empty.

```
if(fuActionAttachment.HasFile)
   {
      //save statement
   }
```

I have tried to put `enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"` on my form tag in my masterpage and still won't work. On my other pages, I do have the same file upload method and they are working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File Upload dosen't work properly inside an Update Panel...This is well known issue..

Try this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUploadImage" runat="server">
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuldImage" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>


<asp:LinkButton ID="btnbUpload" runat="server" onclick="btnbUpload_Click">Add</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>


</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger   ControlID="btnbUpload"/></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Nothing happens...:)You need to add a trigger to btnUload

Comment: So, the user have to click the btn just to upload the file?

Comment: Yes..Update panel has lots of problems and dosen't work properly with most of the controls.